# Spring Cannot deserialize request param date "Thu Dec 26 20:53:18 GMT+01:00 2019"

Tags: java, spring-boot

Cannot parse "Thu Dec 26 20:53:18 GMT+01:00 2019" using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern ="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'XXX yyyy")`.

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.util.Date] for value 'Thu Dec 26 20:53:18 GMT+01:00 2019'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Thu Dec 26 20:53:18 GMT+01:00 2019" is malformed at "+01:00 2019"]
```

Comment: don't use [java.util.Date][1] it is just instant of time and doesn't store any offset, use `OffSetDateTime` from java-8 it will work

Comment: Try replacing 'GMT'XXX with 'OOOO'; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Deadpool and @Stephen C, Combining your answers solved my problem.

```
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX";

public filter(@DateTimeFormat(pattern =DATE_TIME_FORMAT) LocalDate fromDate) {
...
}
```

I updated date format as well.